# How to use EnableJpaAuditing annotation in Spring boot to wrtite @CreatedDate in Indian Standard Time i.e. UTC+05:30?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, audit

My Models extend this AuditModel

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true
)
public abstract class AuditModel implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

     //getters and setters

}
```

I have added below line to ***application.properties***

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

**But I want time to be UTC+05:30 in my database entries. How to do that ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your main application class or other appropriate bean you can add a PostConstruct to set the Timezone throughout your application and that will be honoured by the Auditing tags (below is UTC as an example)

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))
}
```

Comment: Though there may be complications if you are persisting to a timestamp with timezone column - fine if it is just a timestamp.